# How to read three TCP/IP RFID readers using a router using a PC application?

Tags: c#, arrays, tcp

I have purchased 3 RFID readers which are TCP/IP compatible. I have started by first connecting one reader to my my router and also connected my PC to the same router. I have adjusted the reader's IP to match the routers IP, so the PC can communicate with the reader. I use the following code to connect to the reader:

```
private void connect_reader(string IP)
    {
        try
        {
            if (device.ConnectDevice(IP, 4501) == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Boolean flag = device.StopReadTag();
                    flag = device.StopReadTag();
                    if (true == flag)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Reader connected successfully.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        EnableButtons();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Reader not connected successfully.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        device.DisConnectDivice();
                        button_OpenPort.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Reader not connected successfully.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    device.DisConnectDivice();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Reader not connected successfully.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The following code is used to disconnect from the reader:

```
private void disconnect_reader()
    {
        device.DisConnectDivice();
        MessageBox.Show("Reader disconnected successfully.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        button_OpenPort.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The reader connects successfully to the PC using the application. My router also has two more additional ethernet ports and therefore I would like to connect another two readers to the router.

My application is to extract the ID from the RFID tags when there are read by the RFID readers. I also want to know what reader scanned that particular RFID tag. For example, I have three readers with the following IP addresses: reader1(192.168.4.100), reader2(192.168.4.101), and readers(192.168.4.102). Now position those three readers at three different positions in an apartment. A person with an RFID tag walks pass reader2, reader2 then scans the RFID tag and relays the info back to the application. First, the application can only connect to one antenna only. So what I want to do is to store all the IP addresses of the three readers in an array, as shown below. Then I want to loop through each reader for a period of time. So in the example above when the RFID tag is detected my reader2, the application will store the RFID tag ID and also assign the RFID tag ID to reader2.

My question is, therefore, in the above code I was thinking of just storing the IP addresses of each reader in the array and then connect to one reader at a time. So for instances:

```
void reader() //example method
{
   array string reader_ip[] = {192.168.4.100; 192.168.4.101; 192.168.4.102};

   for(int i = 0; i <4; i++) //Loop through all readers by connecting to the reader via their IP addresses for a period of time them disconnect from the reader and then connect to the other reader.
   {
     connect_reader(reader_ip[i]); //Connects to the specific reader 
     readTags(); //readTags that are detected by the connected reader
     disconnect_reader(); disconnects to the specific reader 
     timeDelay(); //time delay of 2secs before reconnecting to the next reader
   }
}
```

Is this the correct way for switching between the networked readers, in order to obtain the data that is scanned by the different readers?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. It's hard to say what is correct without some more details about what you are trying to do. For example; in your example method you are suggesting to connect to only one reader in turn which seems a little odd. What is your application? Also, you may receive some down votes I'm afraid since this is more of a code review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than it is a specific question.

Comment: That's not an application, an application would be some detail such as: "I have three RFID reader that I need to poll in parallel at 60Hz. I expect each reader to return 1-100 unique tag IDs per second, etc etc". If you don't offer detail, no one can make you a recommendation. Otherwise the answer is no, it's not correct since continuously connecting/disconnecting hardware in series is wasteful. Why not have perpetual connections?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I have amended the post. I hope the application is clear. What are perpetual connections?

Comment: That's very helpful detail, yes. By perpetual connections I mean that you connect to each reader once at the being on your application and maintain the connections until you are finished. I'll work on an answer for you and post shortly.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood thank you for helping and clarifying my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing which manufacturer or SDK you are working with, I can only make you some suggestions in pseudo code.

**Main Point:** The example code you have provided is limiting you since you have chosen to have one `device` which I have understood to be an instance of an `RFIDReader` class. I would recommend you take an approach of having a collection of `RFIDReader`, that you connect to a single time at the being of your application, and maintain those connections until you are finished. That may look something like this:

In the following, I use a made up class called `RFIDReader`. It can `Connect()`, `Disconnect()`, and `GrabTags()` which simple up dates a the property of `Tags`, a collection of the tags in detected:

```
public class RFIDReader
{
    // Container property for detected tags
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; private set; }

    // Connection Methods
    public void Connect(string ipAdress) { }
    public void Disconnect() { }

    // Polling Method
    public void GrabTags()
    {
        // Tags = GrabMeSomeTags()
    }
}
```

In the console application example below, (again all pseudo, no error checking etc), I have chosen to use a `System.Timers.Timer` to "Poll" all three readers in turn, every 2000ms:

```
class Program
{
    // An array of your three RFID readers
    static RFIDReader[] rFIDReaders = new RFIDReader[3];
    // An array of the three IPAdresses
    static string[] ipAdress = new string[3]
    {
            "192.168.4.100",
            "192.168.4.101",
            "192.168.4.102"
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // A timer for polling the readers, every 2000ms (2 seconds)
        Timer pollTimer = new Timer(2000);
        pollTimer.Elapsed += PollTimer_Elapsed;

        // Setup
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Connecting to reader {i} at IPAdress {ipAdress[i]}");
            rFIDReaders[i].Connect(ipAdress[i]);
        }

        // Start Timer
        Console.WriteLine("Starting reader polling...");
        pollTimer.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("System Running.");

        // Wait for user to Exit
        Console.WriteLine("Press any ket to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Stop the timer
        pollTimer.Stop();

        // Disconnect the RFIDReaders
        foreach (RFIDReader rFIDReader in rFIDReaders)
        {
            rFIDReader.Disconnect();
        }
    }

    private static void PollTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(RFIDReader rFIDReader in rFIDReaders)
        {
            rFIDReader.GrabTags();
        }
    }
}
```

This solution will hold on `Console.ReadKey();`, mean while, every two seconds the `Timer.Elapsed` event invokes the handler `PollTimer_Elapsed`. You could use any mechanism for your application continuing of course (perhaps you have some Form/WPF GUI?), but key is that the timer will regularly have the `RFIDReaders` update they're own collection of `Tag` for your analysis.

Comment: thank you, but how do I associate the RFID tag with the reader that read that particular tag? I think I don't follow completely.

Comment: No problem. You have three `RFIDReader` in your array, and in each one has a property `Tags` which is a `List<Tag>`. Every time a `RFIDReader` calls `.GrabTags()`, it updates it's own `Tags` property. For example, `rFIDReaders[0].Tags` will return a collection of `Tag` detected by that specific reader. This part is a bit of a "secondary question" following the multiple connections part. It's hard to save if my solution here is appropriate, it depends a lot on your application need and the manufacturer/SDK you are using.

Comment: If I am also on the page as you. So all readers are connected using the `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`. Then once all the readers area connected which is called using the `public void Connect(string ipAdress) { }` method. The timer starts. Now every 2 seconds the `PollTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)` is called. Then this  `foreach(RFIDReader rFIDReader in rFIDReaders)` grabs the info from the RFID tags. The timer then starts again and process loops from then one until the exit key is pressed and then the readers are disconnected. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, sounds like you've understood. The key point in answer to your original question is that you have three readers, all of which are connected. You are not connecting, and disconnecting each one in turn.

Comment: Is it okay if I post my email and you can reply so I can send you the SDK?

Comment: Sure. I can't promise I have a lot of time to spare. However I'll try and point you in the right direction. Generally on here people are looking to answer, individual, specific questions. Try and break up you questions part-by-part if you can :)